# How I upload my web Service(REST api, in java) that works locally to a host server

Tags: java, android, web-services, restful-url

I just mad a web service(REST api) in java that works locally but I don't have any idea how I upload it to a host server. I found some free host servers and got my server but I don't know how to upload my web service. can someone can give my some tips how to do it? thanks :]

Comment: Does you code generate a war file?

Comment: yes I can generate a war file, how does it help me? (sorry for the noob question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems not to be an Android question... but anyways :)

You may need to dig a bit more on how to host applications in general. For people with not much knowledge on infrastructure or not willing to learn how to manage everything by themselves I suggest using services like Heroku.

For deploying your web service to heroku, you simply push the same way you push to a git server. If you no nothing about `git`, it is time to drop everything and go learn the basics.

It has a free tier and start charging you once your needs grow over that tier: https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/java